# Reset NSUserDefault key everyday in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing an app which requires to reset a key stored in NSUserDefaults every day. (At 00:00 hours)

I have achieved this but the method I used is a messy and unreliable one.

Is there an easy way to achieve my goal?

Here is the code.

```
    extension NSDate
    {

        func month() -> Int
        {
            let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
            let components = calendar.components(.Month, fromDate: self)
            let month = components.month
            return month
        }


        func date() -> Int
        {
            let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
            let components = calendar.components(.Day, fromDate: self)
            let date = components.day

            return date
        }

        func hour() -> Int
        {
            //Get Hour
            let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
            let components = calendar.components(.Hour, fromDate: self)
            let hour = components.hour

            //Return Hour
            return hour
        }


        func minute() -> Int
        {
            //Get Minute
            let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
            let components = calendar.components(.Minute, fromDate: self)
            let minute = components.minute

            //Return Minute
            return minute
        }

        func toShortTimeString() -> String
        {
            //Get Short Time String
            let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
            let timeString = formatter.stringFromDate(self)

            //Return Short Time String
            return timeString
        }
    }


class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var totalcounterme:Int! //stored variable
    let currentDate = NSDate() //current date
    var todaysDate:Int! //date variable for storing local value




    @IBOutlet weak var todayTotal: UILabel! //total cigarrete count value

    @IBOutlet weak var numberC: UITextField! //text label value

    @IBAction func countPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        var counter = totalcounterme //add local value to the counter
        if numberC.text != "" {
        counter = counter + Int(numberC.text!)! //add input value to counter
        numberC.text = ""
        todayTotal.text = "\(counter)" //display value of counter
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(counter, forKey: "storedCounter") //store counter value
        totalcounterme = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("storedCounter") //return stored value
        todaysDate = currentDate.date()
            if todaysDate > NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("finaldate") {
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(0, forKey: "storedCounter")

            } else if todaysDate < NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("finaldate") {
                if currentDate.month() > NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("finalmonth") {
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(0, forKey: "storedCounter")
                }
            }

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(todaysDate, forKey: "finaldate") //set todays date in value
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(currentDate.month(), forKey: "finalmonth") //set month

        }
        }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let month = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("finalmonth")
        let today = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("finaldate")
        if currentDate.date() > today {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(0, forKey: "storedCounter")
        } else if currentDate.date() < today {
            if currentDate.month() > month {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(0, forKey: "storedCounter")
            }
        }

        totalcounterme = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("storedCounter")

        todayTotal.text = "\(totalcounterme)"

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have currently, that way we can best help decide how to improve.

Comment: It is a lazy code. But anyway I will put it up in a moment. @Otra

Comment: The problem it is the way you are trying to accomplish your task. No need to do that at midnight. Just save the date you saved your settings and next time the user opens the app check if that date is in same day as today otherwise reset it

Comment: @LeoDabus I have done exactly what you have said. I am putting my code over here. I want to know if there is a better way of doing that

Comment: I think you should also be questioning whether you should be using `NSUserDefaults` for this or not. `NSUserDefaults` are used for user ***preferences***. I don't think a user would be expecting a given preference to reset every day...

Comment: @originaluser2 i am using NSUserDefaults because I don't have to save a lot of variables and I was developing the app for my personal use. Just kidding, this is the only method I know to save variables locally.

Comment: @Sanidhay have a look at `NSKeyedArchiver` or using an `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` and using their `writeToFile:` methods.

Comment: NSCalendar has a method called isDateInToday https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/isDateInToday:

Comment: Thanks for the info @originaluser2

Comment: I am pretty sure you want to keep standardUserDefaults in there.

Comment: ... though a `let standardUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` wouldn't hurt.

Comment: what you need is a background task that will evaluate if the defaults exist after a condition is met

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a NSUserDefault extension computed property with a getter and a setter to save the user last access date. NSCalendar has a method called isDateInToday that you can use inside your setter to removePersistentDomainForName if the last access date is not in same day as today:

```
extension UserDefaults {

    static let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    static var lastAccessDate: Date? {
        get {
            return defaults.object(forKey: "lastAccessDate") as? Date
        }
        set {
            guard let newValue = newValue else { return }
            guard let lastAccessDate = lastAccessDate else {
                defaults.set(newValue, forKey: "lastAccessDate")
                return
            }
            if !Calendar.current.isDateInToday(lastAccessDate) {
                print("remove Persistent Domain")
                UserDefaults.reset()
            }
            defaults.set(newValue, forKey: "lastAccessDate")
        }
    }

    static func reset() {
        defaults.removePersistentDomain(forName: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "")
    }
}
```

Just set your user last access date when your user opens your app:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UserDefaults.lastAccessDate = Date()
}
```

Comment: can you please explain how to check whether the date has changed or not?

Comment: every time you set a date inside the setter there is a conditional If not (!) date is in sameDayAsToday remove persistent domain