# Is there any way to know how long my iPhone app wasn't opened using swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a health app. I have to access the health data of the user from Pedometer or HealthKit if the user isn't open the app for a certain period of time like days, week or months. Is there any way to know how long the app wasn't opened when my app runs again?

Comment: Just log it e.g. in UserDefaults, when app starts, then you know

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/35047928/2303865

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You can save "current date" when your app is closed.

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "Date")
    }
```

And then, when app is launching, get current date and compare with `"Date"`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let passedTime : TimeInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Date") as! Date)
}
```

You can also get `Date()` from some server if don't want that the user can alter it.

EDIT: As suggested by Leo Dabus, you can check if UserDefaults is present this way (and in many others)

```
if let userDefaultDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Date") {
    // Present
} else {
    // First time
}
```

Comment: This will crash the app the first time you launch the app. There will be no value saved in UserDefaults when you try to retrieve it.

Comment: I am not the OP

Comment: I know... My solution is not intended to be ready for "copy and paste". There are many way you can check for UserDefaults.

Comment: Good to know, but don't you need to compare it with last access date? So what is different?

Comment: If you are talking about the link I posted it is a different question and you do need to check if the last access date was in the same day as the current access. How would you do it without it?

Comment: Now your user default date it is not a date. It is an object of type Any

Comment: Don’t get me wrong. We don’t know how much the OP knows about coding and/or Swift

Comment: You are right, and I have many things to learn too... Please, feel free to edit my answer if it can improve

Comment: I probably wouldn't log the data in `applicationWillTerminate` - that function isn't always called.  Probably `didEnterBackground` is a better place.